# Play 2.x and multi-tenancy

Tags: java, asynchronous, playframework-2.0, multi-tenant

I'm implementing a multy-tenant application with Play Framework 2.0. For that I added to eban configuration two adapters:

```
public class TenantBeanQueryAdapter implements BeanQueryAdapter {

    ...

    @Override
    public void preQuery(BeanQueryRequest<?> beanQueryRequest) {
        Query query = beanQueryRequest.getQuery();
        query.where().eq(this.tenantManager.getFieldName(),this.tenantManager.getValue().toString());
    }

}


public class TenantBeanPersistController implements BeanPersistController{

    ...

    @Override
    public boolean preInsert(BeanPersistRequest<?> request) {
        try {
            Field field = request.getBean().getClass().getDeclaredField(tenantManager.getFieldName());
            field.setAccessible(true);
            field.set(request.getBean(),tenantManager.getValue());
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

These adapters are getting the tenant id from the session. The problems are with Ebean, it uses Futures to make some queries. The TenantManager gets the tenant_id from the session and the session is stored in a ThreadLocal. The result is:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no HTTP Context available from here.
```

I have been researching and I have considered ExecutorService and  InheritableThreadLocal (as it's suggested here [propagation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259906/propagating-threadlocal-to-a-new-thread-fetched-from-a-executorservice)) but I think that Play don't let me replace Ebean's backgroundExecutor and  InheritableThreadLocal don't work.

Any suggestion?

Thanks,

Comment: I don't known play, but maybe you can set context with GlobalProperties.setServletContext(context), before the execution.