# How-to provide a ThreadLocal to CompletableFutures?

Tags: java, java-8, java.util.concurrent

I need to provide a `ThreadLocal` to all the threads which end up running specific `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync` Suppliers.

From the javadoc I see that `CompletableFuture` uses "`ForkJoinPool commonPool()`" which very much fits my performance use case.

How do I transfer a `ThreadLocal` (and afterwards delete) to all pool threads running a specific CompletableFuture Supplier?

Remark:

I see that  all `CompletableFuture  async` completion methods accept an Executor. I would love to use the
default `ForkJoinPool commonPool()` but if this is not possible I guess I have to override `ThreadPoolExecutor` and implement `beforeExecute`?

Comment: Why do you need to have it as ThreadLocal? Can't you store the value inside your `CompletableFuture`? If we know how you queue your tasks we might be able to suggest a wraper which takes care anyway.

Comment: good question. It is because I am using in the CompletableFuture Task a framework (like Hibernate) which uses config data in Thread Locals. Its difficult for me to reach the Classes that depend on the Thread locals

Comment: You can use the same approach with `Supplier`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you'll have to find your own way arround it as `exec()` on `ForkJoinTask` is protected. For concrete implementations you can of course write your own wrapper.

This is what I would do for a single `ThreadLocal` and a `Callable`:

```
public static class WithThreadLocal<V, T> implements Callable<V> {
    private final ThreadLocal<T> threadLocal;
    private final T              value;
    private final Callable<V>    callable;


    public WithThreadLocal(ThreadLocal<T> threadLocal, T value, Callable<V> callable) {
        this.threadLocal = threadLocal;
        this.value = value;
        this.callable = callable;
    }

    @Override
    public V call() throws Exception {
        T oldValue = threadLocal.get();
        try {
            threadLocal.set(value);
            return callable.call();
        } finally {
            threadLocal.set(oldValue);
        }
    }
}
```

From there you can use [`ForkJoinTask.adapt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinTask.html#adapt-java.util.concurrent.Callable-). Otherwise you might be interrested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/7260332/1266906