# Passing a ThreadLocal variable to a EJB container Thread pool

Tags: jakarta-ee, asynchronous, websphere, ejb-3.0, thread-local

I have a InheritableThreadLocal variable which I want to pass to another child Thread allocated by the Thread pool of the EJB container as a result of a Async call to a public EJB method. The parent caller initiating the Async call is a REST resource which is a Stateless EJB.
 InheritableThreadLocal passes value to its child thread only when the child thread is created new. Once a thread is created in the pool it never destroys the Thread till the server is bounced.

Considering the above facts, the child thread for my case comes from a Threadpool maintained by the EJB container. The InheritableThreadLocal passing value to its child thread only when Resource is invoked for the first time after a server starts or if a brand new Thread which just got created in Threadpool is allocated as a child thread. In all other cases I am getting the initial value what got assigned to the child thread from the pool when the Thread got created and allocated for the 1st time.

I am running my code on IBM WebSphere and Passing the ThreadLocal value as a method parameter in the Async call is not an option.

How I can reassign the ThreadLocal value so that for each run I can get the current value assigned to the child thread?

I found the below link which is somewhat similar but for my case the ThreadPool is what provided by the EJB container.

[Propagating ThreadLocal to a new Thread fetched from a ExecutorService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259906/propagating-threadlocal-to-a-new-thread-fetched-from-a-executorservice)

Comment: If you don't get an answer, let me suggest adding some code snippets so it's easier for someone reading to make sure they're following along correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Using ThreadLocal is not a portable way. You need to know exact how the container handle threads.

From my perspective a ThreadLocal is save as in general the container use the same thread to process a sequence of sync Servler/REST/EJB invocations.
If Async come into play this will not work.

I would use a portable way like parameters or persistence.