# How to keep context when creating new thread in spring?

Tags: java, spring

```
System.out.println(LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()); // zh
new Thread(() -> {
    System.out.println(LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()); // en_US
}).start();
```

From parent thread, I see that context locale is "zh" from child thread, I see "en_US". New thread is losing the context locale. Is there a way to pass context to new created thread?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44033816/733345 has an example of this.

Comment: Thanks @Joe it solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Javadocs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/i18n/LocaleContextHolder.html)

> The LocaleContext will be inherited by any child threads spawned by the current thread if the inheritable flag is set to true.

This means locale can be set using the method  `setLocale(Locale locale, boolean inheritable)` by passing `inheritable` as true. So before spawning a new child thread you can call setLocale with `inheritable` equals to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

use `transmittable-thread-local`,add dependence to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
  <artifactId>transmittable-thread-local</artifactId>
  <version>2.12.0</version>
</dependency>
```

convert you executorService like this

```
ExecutorService executorService = ...
executorService = TtlExecutors.getTtlExecutorService(executorService);
```