# InheritableThreadLocal value not inherited by ExecutorService threads

Tags: java, scala, concurrency, thread-local

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}

object TestInheritableThreadLocal {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2))

    val tl: InheritableThreadLocal[String] = new InheritableThreadLocal[String]()
    tl.set("InitialValue")

    Future {
      println("111 " + Thread.currentThread() + tl.get())
      Future {
        println("222 " + Thread.currentThread() + tl.get())
      }
    }
    Thread.sleep(3000)

    Future {
      tl.set("NewInitialValue")
      println("333 " + Thread.currentThread() + tl.get())
      Future {
        println("444 " + Thread.currentThread() + tl.get())
      }
      Thread.sleep(3000)
    }
  }
}
```

Output

```
111 Thread[pool-1-thread-1,5,main]InitialValue
222 Thread[pool-1-thread-2,5,main]InitialValue
333 Thread[pool-1-thread-1,5,main]NewInitialValue
444 Thread[pool-1-thread-2,5,main]InitialValue
```

I was expecting "NewInitialValue" in the last line of output since 333 Thread spawned of Thread 444 and tl is a Inheritable thread local.

What is causing this issue and how can it be resolved ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You shouldn't rely on [`InheritableThreadLocal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/InheritableThreadLocal.html) when you don't have control over the creation of threads. The javadoc states:

> [...] when a child thread is created, the child receives initial values for
>   all inheritable thread-local variables for which the parent has
>   values.

In your example, threads are being created by the `ExecutorService` returned by [`Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool-int-)

That's an executor that will use up to two threads to execute your tasks. From the javadoc

> Creates a thread pool that reuses a fixed number of threads operating
>   off a shared unbounded queue. At any point, at most `nThreads` threads
>   will be active processing tasks. If additional tasks are submitted
>   when all threads are active, they will wait in the queue until a
>   thread is available.

This is an implementation detail, but those threads are created lazily, as needed.  When you submit the first task, `111`, the call to `submit` will create and start a new thread. This new thread will inherit the value `InitialValue`. Similarly, when this thread submits the second task, `222`, its call to `submit` will force the creation of the second thread which will also inherit the `InitialValue`.

Then you submit the third task, `333`, overwrite the `InheritableThreadLocal`'s value and print it. When you submit the fourth task `444`, the `ExecutorService` uses existing threads to execute it. That thread already has a value, inherited earlier.

> how can it be resolved

That's hard to answer without knowing what you want to do. But, if you want to effectively use `InheritableThreadLocal`, it all comes down to knowing and controlling the creation of threads, and therefore the inheritance chain.

You could create and use an `ExecutorService` that creates and uses a new thread for each submitted task, for example.

Similarly, you could use another mechanism to propagate that value: an `AtomicReference` or lambda capture of an immutable value.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the thread names in the output, you can see that there are two threads(as per your `ExecutionContext` configuration) `pool-1-thread-1` and `pool-1-thread-2`.

`444` thread is reusing the thread `pool-1-thread-2` which was previously used by `222` with `tl` already assigned.

`333` thread is reusing `pool-1-thread-1` which was previously used by `111` with `tl` already assigned, but it's overwriting the inherited `InitialValue` to `NewInitialValue`.

You might see a different output if you increase the no. of threads. This is what I get with

three threads:

```
111 Thread[pool-1-thread-1,5,main]InitialValue
222 Thread[pool-1-thread-2,5,main]InitialValue
333 Thread[pool-1-thread-3,5,main]NewInitialValue
444 Thread[pool-1-thread-2,5,main]InitialValue // Reusing "pool-1-thread-2"
```

four threads:

```
111 Thread[pool-1-thread-1,5,main]InitialValue
222 Thread[pool-1-thread-2,5,main]InitialValue
333 Thread[pool-1-thread-3,5,main]NewInitialValue
444 Thread[pool-1-thread-4,5,main]NewInitialValue // Fresh thread "pool-1-thread-4"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Spring Integration and using an executor to process split messages.
Faced the same issue during this.

@Soritos is right

> That's hard to answer without knowing what you want to do

What workaround I did was

1. Added the ThreadLocal variable in MessageHeaders.
2. In the message Splitter, created a new InhertiableThreadLocal  and assign value from the MessageHeaders

   ```
    if (null != message.getHeaders().get("frameworkCorrelationID")) {
       private static final InheritableThreadLocal<String> id = new InheritableThreadLocal(); 
       id.set((String)message.getHeaders().get("frameworkCorrelationID"));    }
   ```